# calling base constructor passing in a value

Tags: c#

```
public DerivedClass(string x) : base(x)
{
  x="blah";
}
```

will this code call the base constructor with a value of x as "blah"?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The base call is always done first, but you *can* make it call a static method. For example:

```
public Constructor(string x) : base(Foo(x))
{
    // stuff
}

private static string Foo(string y)
{
    return y + "Foo!";
}
```

Now if you call

```
new Constructor("Hello ");
```

then the base constructor will be called with "Hello Foo!".

Note that you *cannot* call instance methods on the instance being constructed, as it's not "ready" yet.

Comment: I want to pass in long string of text to the base constructor, so is using your approach the best for this? i.e calling a static Foo method that will return the long string of text and call the base constructor with that.

Comment: You certainly can do - do you actually need your constructor to take a parameter in that case? Are you going to pass the same string up to the base constructor in every case?

Comment: No my constructor won't need it in that case. For every new class that derives from the base class it will have a different "long string of text" that will be needed by the base constructor

Comment: One option would be not to have it passed into the base constructor, but to make it a protected abstract property that the base class could call when it needed to. Alternatively, just have a const string in each class and pass that into the base. (There's no need for the method call at that point.)

Comment: @Jon: Just to add a note to your "protected abstract" solution: it's not recommended to call any virtual (or abstract, for that matter) member of a non-sealed class in its constructor. The rationale behind this is that the overriden member in a derived class will run *before* the constructor of the derived class is run (and the class might be in an uninitialized state). Thus if that overriden method relies on certain variables to be initialized properly by the constructor, it'll fail to function correctly.

Comment: Yes - I would only ever do that if absolutely necessary with *massive* documentation along those lines. However, it's possible that the property may not be required until after the constructor has finished, in which case it's not such a problem.

Answer (score 5):

No, `base` call we be performed before executing the constructor body:

```
//pseudocode (invalid C#):
public Constructor(string x) {
   base(x);
   x = "blah";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the base constructor is always called before the current constructor.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will call it with the value passed into the derived class constructor. Base class constructor is always called (explicitly or implicitly) prior to executing the body of the derived class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

No, It won't. The base constructor will be passed the string in x **before** the execution of DerivedClass constructor. This may work:

```
public DerivedClass(string x) : base("Blah")
{ }
```

I'm not sure about that but you should be able to call any method / getter when calling the base constructor, like that:

```
public DerivedClass(DateTime x) : base(DateTime.Now)
{ }
```

Comment: Not *any* method - only static ones.

Comment: `DateTime.Now` is a property so you should remove the parens but yeah, it's possible to do that.

Comment: @Jon: ... or instance methods of other objects.

Comment: @ Mehrdad - yes, sorry about that (these are the effects of learning java...)

Comment: @Jon: AFAIK you can call any method or access any getter or public field of any object other than the one you are constructing.

Comment: @Utaal and Mehrdad: Yup, that's a more precise way of saying it. (I made my own answer somewhat clearer :)